How to speed up the passage of a nested loop in Python
How to speed up the passage of a nested loop. I am doing browser automation using Selenium and in one section of the code I need to compare coefficients and dates with table cells. The code needs about 30 seconds to go around the entire plate, about 6 rows and 6 columns.
    def __parse_full_page(self, url: str, data: dict = {}) -> bool:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(Locator.PLAN)).click()
            cells = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(Locator.CELLS_TABLE))
            current_url = str(self.driver.current_url)
            id_ticket = current_url.split("&")[-2].split("=")[-1]
            button_planning = self.driver.find_element(*Locator.CONFIRM)

            ticket_data = tickets.get(id_ticket)

            if ticket_data != "Заявка не найдена":
                _, max_rate = ticket_data.split(':')
                max_rate = int(max_rate)
            else: max_rate = 0

            coefficients = ["Бесплатно"] + [f'✕{i}' for i in range(1, max_rate + 1)]
            
            for coefficient in coefficients:
                for cell in cells:
                    try:
                        date_text = cell.find_element(*Locator.DATE).text
                        try:
                            date_text_clean = date_text.split(',')[0].strip()
                            date_object = datetime.strptime(date_text_clean, "%d %B")
                            date_object = date_object.replace(year=datetime.now().year)
                        except ValueError as ve:
                            print(f"Ошибка при преобразовании даты: {ve}")
                            continue

                        buffer_days = int(config["BOT"]["BUFFER"])
                        today = datetime.now()
                        buffer_date = today + timedelta(days=buffer_days)

                        if date_object > buffer_date:
                            coefficient_element = cell.find_element(*Locator.RATE)
                            coefficient_text = coefficient_element.text
                            if coefficient_text.strip() == f"{coefficient}":
                                button_hover = cell.find_element(*Locator.CHOOSE_HOVER)
                                self.action.move_to_element(button_hover).perform()
                                try:
                                    cell.find_element(*Locator.CHOOSE).click()
                                    self.action.move_to_element(button_planning).click().perform()
                                    new_id_el = self.driver.find_element(*Locator.ID).text
                                    new_id = new_id_el.strip()
                                    logger.debug("ЗАЯВКА ПРОШЛА")
                                    self.__pretty_log({"id_ticket": id_ticket, 'coefficient': coefficient, 'date': date_text, "new_id": new_id})
                                    return True
                                except Exception as e:
                                    print(f"Ошибка при нажатии 'Выбрать': {e}")
                            else:
                                continue

                        else:
                            continue

                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Ошибка: {e}")
                        continue

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка: {e}")

        return False



Need to speed up for coefficient in coefficients: for cell in cells:
The cycle runs through the WebElement
I do not know how to speed it up.

Do you know that the slow code is inside the two for loops and not in the preamble where you call WebDriverWait()?

@JonSG Yes, I know, I wrote about it

Not being a selenium expert by any stretch, what is Locator? Micro optimization, buffer_date can probably be calculated outside the loops.

First I would remove this code from inner loop probably won't help much but doesn't appear it needs to be done there:
buffer_days = int(config["BOT"]["BUFFER"])
today = datetime.now()
buffer_date = today + timedelta(days=buffer_days)

Next is based on what you gave, without testing it myself. You are using a mouse action which tends to be slow:
self.action.move_to_element(button_planning).click().perform()

If this can be done in some other way, it should improve the performance (either click on the button directly or use JavaScript execute). If you have to have the action chain, you could try splitting it. It sometimes works faster.
self.action.move_to_element(button_planning).perform()
button_planning.click()

